# Arcpy query String field

Tags: arcpy, sql, cursor

I have numerous shapefiles with two fields, "ID2" (Integer) and "FILENAME" (String). Using arcpy I'm trying to query the attribute table for rows that have a certain value ("SCN_TCV_001_2002") in FILENAME and for those rows find the max value of the ID2 field. I think I'm just missing something in the query syntax. My code is below which returns an error at the last line "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getValue'". I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 with an Advanced License.

```
import arcpy, os, sys
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:\\folder1"
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fclist:
    field1 = 'FILENAME'
    field2 = 'ID2'

    sWhereClause = '"' + field1 + '"' + ' = ' + "'" +  "SCN_TCV_001_2002" + "'"

    maxValue = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, sWhereClause, "", "", field2 + " D").next().getValue(field2)
```

Comment: does it give you an error when it "crashes"

Comment: Yes, the error is:

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
NameError: name 'SCN_TCV_001_2002' is not defined

Comment: Okay just tried that and now I'm getting a new error:

RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used.

Comment: so the error is saying that your value is not assigned to a variable. you need to wrap it quotes to indicate its a string or assign a variable with that value.please update your code to reflect any updates you make.

Comment: Without looking too deeply into your logic, remove the "" around the sWhereClause in the arcpy.SearchCursor statement.  You need to reference the variable sWhereClasuse, not the string "sWhereClause"

Comment: Okay, in the sWhereClause line I have placed quotes around "SCN_TCV_001_2002".  In the maxValue line I have removed the quotes around "sWhereClause".  Now when I run the error is:   Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 13, in <module> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getValue'

Comment: Your goal is to find the one row with highest value in ID2 where filename = "SCN_TCV_001_2002"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use the newer Data Access cursor, like the [da.SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm). They are alot faster.

Also it's difficult to get SQL queries like this to work:

```
sWhereClause = '"' + field1 + '"' + ' = ' + "'" +  "SCN_TCV_001_2002" + "'"
```

For example the quotation signs are different depending on type of indata (shape, features in a file geodatabase, etc.).

Try using [AddFieldDelimiters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) and [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
sWhereClause = """{0} = 'SCN_TCV_001_2002'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc,field1))
```

Comment: Thanks @BERA. I have tried this approach yet still get the error:   Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 13, in <module> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getValue'

Comment: Try using the da cursor

Comment: Okay, just tried that and now a new error tells me "Line 13, a column specified does not exist. I must have the "ID2" column referenced wrong in the code?

Comment: Now I see the syntax is different for arcpy.da.cursor, which is as follows:  SearchCursor (in_table, field_names, {where_clause}, {spatial_reference}, {explode_to_points}, {sql_clause}).  I have now set it up like so:  maxValue = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field2, "sWhereClause", "", "", sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY ID2')). I am unsure how to extract the max value from this.

Comment: You're changing the question three comments deep into an answer. Extracting the max just requires an extra test.

Comment: @Vince My question remains the same, that is to find the max value of ID2 given a certain value for FILENAME. I also have been updating the code in my original question as I receive input from users as requested in the comments above.